# Angular 5 Dynamically change images ngFor according to Array function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to get an image to dynamically change on the HTML with ngFor

so what I did is:

looping through an Array and change the value of a variable according to the current weather:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { WeatherService } from '../weather.service';
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather-component',
  templateUrl: './weather.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather.component.css']
})
export class WeatherComponent implements OnInit {

  weatherImg: string;
  clouds: string;
  sun: string;

  public shown = false;
  cityName: string;
  weathers: any = [];
  forecasts: any = [];
  weatherType: string;
  forecastType: string;
  forecastImg: string;

  constructor(private _weatherService: WeatherService) {


  }

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(this.submitDataBox.bind(this, this.cityName), 60000);
    setInterval(this.submitData.bind(this, this.cityName), 60000);
    setInterval(this.weatherImage.bind(this), 10000);
  }

weatherImage() {

 // const weatherType = this.weathers.weather[0].main;

for (let i = 0, len = this.forecasts.list.length; i < len; i++) {

        if ( this.forecasts.list[i].weather[0].main.toLowerCase().indexOf('rain') > -1 ) {

        this.forecastImg = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/96/Weather-Rain-icon.png';

        console.log(this.forecasts.list[i].weather[0].main);

} else if (this.forecasts.list[i].weather[0].main.toLowerCase().indexOf('clouds') > -1) {
  this.forecastImg = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/96/Weather-Clouds-icon.png';

}
}
```

And in the component.html:

Five Day Detailed Forecast

```
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mb-4">
        <a href="#">
          <img class="img-fluid" bind-src="forecastImg">
        </a>
        <h5>Date: {{forecast.dt_txt | date : 'short' }}</h5>
            <p > {{ forecast.weather[0].main }}</p>
            <p > {{ forecast.weather[0].description }}</p>
            <p > {{ forecast.weather[0].icon }}</p>
            Temperature <p >{{ forecast.main.temp }}</p>
      </div>



    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
```

But unfortunately the result is that I only get the first image for all the items (http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/96/Weather-Rain-icon.png)

Instead of having the image placed according to the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only creating one forecastImg variable instead of creating one on each instance of forecast.

I've put together a working example where I create a new `image` property on each forecast.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gsbrv9

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting `this.forecastImg`, where `this` is the component, not the `forecast`. And during your loop, you just override the image (actually, you should get the last image for all items, not the first)

What you need to do is create a list of images/forecasts and not just a single image. I assume `this.forecasts` is the result from some http call, so let's just create a new variable at the top of your controller (instead of `forecastImg`). I also suggest using an object to look up the icons instead of if/else:

```
// ideally you create an interface for a forecast
forecastItems: any[] = [];

// create an object for the icons that you can use for lookups
icons = {
  'rain': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/96/Weather-Rain-icon.png',
  'clouds': 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/96/Weather-Clouds-icon.png'
}
```

I'll use ES6 to loop through the forecasts and assign the image to our array

```
for (let item of this.forecasts.list) {
  // here we could use that interface again
  const forecastItem = {
    'title': item.weather[0].main,
    'icon': ''
  }
  // assign the icon if we have one
  try {
    forecastItem['icon'] = this.icons[forecastItem.title.toLowerCase()];
  } catch (e) {}

  // store the object in our helper array
  this.forecastItems.push(forecastItem);
}
```

Now you have an array of forecasts with title and icon, which you use in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let forecast of forecastItems">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mb-4">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" bind-src="forecast.icon" alt="{{ forecast.title }}">
    </a>
  <div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, instead of having a single variable for the image you can do this:

```
this.forecasts.list.forEach((forecast) => { 
if (forecast.weather[0].main.toLowerCase().indexOf('rain') > -1 ) { 
forecast['forecastImg'] = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/96/Weather-Rain-icon.png';
} else if (forecast.weather[0].main.toLowerCase().indexOf('clouds') > -1) { 
forecast['forecastImg'] = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/96/Weather-Clouds-icon.png'; } });
```

Then in your template:

```
  <div *ngFor=" let forecast of forecasts.list">
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mb-4"> 
<a href="#"> 
<img class="img-fluid" bind-src="forecast['forecastImg']">
 </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you close your  tags?

```
<div *ngFor=" let forecast of forecasts.list">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mb-4">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="img-fluid" bind-src="forecastImg">
    </a>
  <div>
<div>
```

Comment: not related, I just left out the irrelevant parts - as I said the loops runs and populates the images. I will add the entire code perhaps to avoid these confusions